# How to disable e.preventDefault for some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a OnePage template of bootstrap, I can not click a link, or can not switch a radio button, someone says I am using e.preventDefault()

Open this page http://abi.maxinrui.com/, you will see what I mean when you click "Click me" on that page.

I check the js file, there are lots of e.preventDefault() and I don't know how to modify them.

Is there a way to disable e.preventDefault()?

I want to have some hyperlink to another websites in my OnePage templete, so here is what I am think: I give some particular elements an ID or class, then I write some js, to disable e.perventDefault() only for these elements.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide your html?

Comment: I'm not too sure about this but I believe you can make it return false

Comment: Sure, the html you can see at http://abi.maxinrui.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery to handle your events, then it's possible!

First, a fiddle (shell for full effect): http://fiddle.jshell.net/UN5WE/show/
Here's the actual fiddle to edit: http://jsfiddle.net/UN5WE/

Basically, we're modifying jQuery's Event object, and specifically, the `preventDefault` method found on the prototype. We maintain a reference to re-enable preventDefault.

**EDIT**
For your specific use case, here's a way to disable preventDefault (based on a class). Just run this script after jQuery has loaded:

```
jQuery.Event.prototype.preventDefault = (function(){
    var originalFunc = jQuery.Event.prototype.preventDefault;
    return function(){
        if($(this.target).hasClass('disableDefault')) {return;}
        originalFunc.call(this);
    }
}())
```

Prior to calling preventDefault, this will check to see if the target has a `disableDefault` class. If it does, it returns immediately (allowing the default to happen). To test your page, copy that code into your console and then run: `$('h1').addClass('disableDefault')`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is possible, or at least not on an easy way that i can think of, you can unbind the handlers if they were setted using bind, but that will also remove any behavior that they have, but you can use a workaround, add a new event handler for your links, i recommend that you add a special class to external anchors and then get the href attribute from it and open a new tab using `window.open` like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/yV78E/2/

The **html**

```
<a href="http://api.jquery.com/?s=selector" class="externalLink" target="_blank">Hey</a>
```

The **js**

```
// Similar behavior that might be on your site  

$('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    // some code
});

// Use the code below as a workaround

$('.externalLink').click(function(e){
    var targetLink = $(this).attr('href'); 
    window.open(targetLink, '_blank');
});
```

You only need the second part of the script above, since the first one is just to emulate your problem.